# Count number of keypress on screen

Tags: c#, keypress

How can I count the number of total key pressed all over the screen in c# application?
Like if the application is running behind and I am typing..then i can see how many keys i have pressed. Thank you.

Comment: Can't you just download [WhatPulse](https://whatpulse.org/)? And what have you tried?

Comment: Are you trying to make a keylogger type of application which logs keyboard input in all the applications. Or you want to log key inputs in just your C# application only?

Comment: How did you open a bounty for 150 points when you only have 1 point to your name?

Comment: @jp2code It subtracts the bounty when you open it, so he probably had slightly more than 150 rep when he opened the bounty.

Answer (score 24):

Found on [MSDN Blogs](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/toub/archive/2006/05/03/589423.aspx):

FOUND:

```
   static class Program
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// The main entry point for the application.
        /// </summary>
        [STAThread]
        static void Main()
        {
            _hookID = SetHook(_proc);

            Application.EnableVisualStyles();
            Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
            Application.Run(new Form1());
            UnhookWindowsHookEx(_hookID);

        }

        private const int WH_KEYBOARD_LL = 13;
        private const int WM_KEYDOWN = 0x0100;
        private static LowLevelKeyboardProc _proc = HookCallback;
        private static IntPtr _hookID = IntPtr.Zero;


        private static IntPtr SetHook(LowLevelKeyboardProc proc)
        {
            using (Process curProcess = Process.GetCurrentProcess())
            using (ProcessModule curModule = curProcess.MainModule)
            {
                return SetWindowsHookEx(WH_KEYBOARD_LL, proc,
                    GetModuleHandle(curModule.ModuleName), 0);
            }
        }

        private delegate IntPtr LowLevelKeyboardProc(
            int nCode, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam);

        private static IntPtr HookCallback(
            int nCode, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam)
        {
            if (nCode >= 0 && wParam == (IntPtr)WM_KEYDOWN)
            {
                int vkCode = Marshal.ReadInt32(lParam);
                Console.WriteLine((Keys)vkCode);
            }
            return CallNextHookEx(_hookID, nCode, wParam, lParam);
        }

        [DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, SetLastError = true)]
        private static extern IntPtr SetWindowsHookEx(int idHook,
            LowLevelKeyboardProc lpfn, IntPtr hMod, uint dwThreadId);

        [DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, SetLastError = true)]
        [return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
        private static extern bool UnhookWindowsHookEx(IntPtr hhk);

        [DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, SetLastError = true)]
        private static extern IntPtr CallNextHookEx(IntPtr hhk, int nCode,
            IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam);

        [DllImport("kernel32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, SetLastError = true)]
        private static extern IntPtr GetModuleHandle(string lpModuleName);
    }
```

Comment: You should really put the source there too.

Answer (score 1):

I would fix the reason your application is running behind (move the code to a background worker?)

And if you still want the global keypresscount after doing that, look at this demoproject that hooks keypress applicationwide in C#

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/19004/A-Simple-C-Global-Low-Level-Keyboard-Hook

Comment: Question is about monitoring keystrokes in -all- applications.

Answer (score 0):

maybe it gives you some idea:

```
private void OnKeyDownHandler(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
  if (e.Key == Key.Return)
  {
     textBlock1.Text = "You Entered: " + textBox1.Text;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Download the Demo project form here :

[Keylogger Project](http://n7a.ziqu.de/Homepages/whitebyte/files/KeyloggerExampleApplication.zip)

and make custom changes what you want.

Answer (score 0):

I use the [ProcessKeyEventArgs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.processkeyeventargs.aspx) like below to capture `Print Screen` key presses in my C# Windows Form.

All I did to modify it was add a counter and increment it.

```
private long counter = 0;

protected override bool ProcessKeyEventArgs(ref Message msg) {
  counter++;
  return base.ProcessKeyEventArgs(ref msg);
}
```